# Generating new variable that removing values less than 0 and greater than 1

Tags: r

Currently, I have generated variable `pscore <- reg1$fit` and created a overlapping histogram with the following code:

```
hist(pscore[data$smoke==1],breaks=40,col=col.alpha("red",.5),freq=FALSE, 
     xlim=c(-0.025,0.529),ylim=c(0,10),xlab="Propensity Score",ylab="",main="")
hist(pscore[data$smoke==0],breaks=20,col=col.alpha("blue",.5),freq=FALSE, 
     ylim=c(0,9),add=TRUE)
```

Mind that variable `smoke` is binary

I'm now trying to create another histogramm but with pscores between 0 and 1

```
pscore2 <- reg1$fit>=0 & reg1$fit <=1
```

R will read it but when running the histogram code with the new pscore, it results in an error.

```
Error in hist.default(pscore2[data$smoke == 1], breaks = 20, col = col.alpha("blue",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
Error in hist.default(pscore2[data$smoke == 0], breaks = 20, col = col.alpha("blue",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

So not sure what other way I could create a new pscore that only has values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
pscore2 <- reg1$fit[reg1$fit >=0 & reg1$fit <=1]
```

Hope it helps.